# How to update excel data by using excel data source in devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using excel data source to bind data from excel to grid view. When I am selected on grid view row I can assign a new value and it's update in excel file.

I want to make sure that when I assign a new value in a grid-view row the same gets updated in the Excel (data source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through documentation : [ExcelDataSource Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.DataAccess.Excel.ExcelDataSource.class)

> The ExcelDataSource component allows you to extract data from
>   Microsoft Excel workbooks (XLS, XLSX or XLSM files) or CSV files
>   stored on the disk or stream. There is also a note that The
>   **ExcelDataSource** works in read-only mode.

Workaround for saving the data back to excel is that you need to manually identity the cells which you have modified and then update them accordingly in the excel sheet for the range of cell you specified during fill operation of grid

Refer these for clarification:
[Binding to Excel Data Sources](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115529/Common-Features/Data-Binding/Binding-to-Excel-Data-Sources)
[Export xtragrid realtime data to excel along with databinding](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T188395/export-xtragrid-realtime-data-to-excel-along-with-databinding)

Comment: can you give me an example like I want to update excel that has ID equal to 1

Comment: @KimRamin: I do not have but let suppose you have a index column in your sheet to identify the records and when you click on the save button then identity the excel row and cell to update the values back.